# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted - using IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I have just started using IDLE for python programming.  I have a problem opening files.  With this simple line of code:

f = open("abc.txt")

I get an error message: PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'abc.txt'

when I run the same code outside of IDLE just using my terminal window it works fine, as you would expect.

Comment: IDLE might be running in a different directory. What does `os.system("pwd")` show?

Comment: I have also tried it with the complete pathname in the file name with same result.  I think it is finding the file because if I mis-spell the file name I get the file not found message.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that IDLE is running as a different user. I'm not sure how this would happen.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate that possibility

Comment: Hey, just for troubleshooting reasons, what are the permissions on the "abc.txt" file?  Is it readable to all users, a select group of users, owner only, etc.?

Comment: Under file info sharing and permissions it says "You can read and write".  This is on a MacBook Pro and I am the only user.